# apache2 reverse proxy inadvertently altering content

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I've configured Apache2 to act as a reverse proxy to a website running in IIS in order to offload SSL and ModSecurity for the site.  It seemed to be working great for most browsers, until I tried accessing the site from an iPad, at which point it became apparent it was rewriting the page a little bit, causing the page to load incorrectly.

I'm able to recreate the issue in another browser if I change the user agent to match the iPad's user agent.

The first few lines of the page's source should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" /><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /><title>

        Login - Intuition by Vertex
</title>
    <link href="/VertexIntuition/Content/images/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png" />

    <script src="/VertexIntuition/bundles/jquery?v=UgyEMAYOuSB9Bb6HcOEVHpd6fIIp54yF086SRNVcdIY1"></script>
<script src="/VertexIntuition/bundles/tablet?v=2kDCvhCBNKBgX0qN9fTU9DAHVqMl3xRFihmIqyYo6hY1"></script>
<link href="/VertexIntuition/Content/style/tabletbundle?v=ItHS3VZO8NwiILS32jviRjVSaLWeZuF0S17HnIT_2Y01" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!-- Framework CSS -->
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/VertexIntuition/Content/style/tablet/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Page specific styles -->

    </head>
<body>
```

When accessing the page via the reverse proxy, the same chunk of the source is rewritten as:

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><title>

        Login - Intuition by Vertex
</title><link href="/VertexIntuition/Content/images/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png"><script src="/VertexIntuition/bundles/jquery?v=UgyEMAYOuSB9Bb6HcOEVHpd6fIIp54yF086SRNVcdIY1"></script><script src="/VertexIntuition/bundles/tablet?v=2kDCvhCBNKBgX0qN9fTU9DAHVqMl3xRFihmIqyYo6hY1"></script><link href="/VertexIntuition/Content/style/tabletbundle?v=ItHS3VZO8NwiILS32jviRjVSaLWeZuF0S17HnIT_2Y01" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Framework CSS --><!--[if lt IE 8]>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/VertexIntuition/Content/style/tablet/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]--><!-- Page specific styles --></head><body>
```

And the page's layout ends up incorrectly formatted (there is more than just this chunk of text that is altered, I'm just using it as an example of the alteration.)

The site's config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/reverseproxy-ssl_error.log
  LogLevel info
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-ssl.log combined

  ProxyRequests off

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyHTMLInterp on

  ProxyPass / http://internal.site.local/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://internal.site.local/

  SetOutputFilter proxy-html
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://internal.site.local /

  RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine On

  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I've completely disabled ModSecurity for now in order to troubleshoot the issue, and the issue is still there, so it shouldn't be that.

The URL I'm using looks something like this:
https://mysite.example.com/VertexIntuition/SystemUser/Login
and again, it seems to work for most other browsers

if I run

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B405 Safari/531.21.10" http://internal.site.local/VertexIntuition/SystemUser/Login"
```

from the server running as the reverse proxy, the page I get appears correct.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there wasn't actually a problem, just a combination of some bizarre caching issue and one of the ModSecurity rules.  My config was fine.

The rule set being triggered, causing the issue was modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf
this caused the incorrect rendering of the page.  The issue persisted after turning off ModSecurity because my browser wasn't properly clearing the cache.